# Why is IHttpAsyncHandler being called over IHttpHandler?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, ihttphandler, ihttpasynchandler

I made a custom handler that derives from MvcHandler.  I have my routes using a custom RouteHandler that returns my new handler for GetHttpHandler(), and I override ProcessRequest() in my custom handler.   The call to GetHttpHandler is triggering a breakpoint and my handler's constructor is definitely being called, but BeginProcessRequest() is being called on the base MvcHandler instead of ProcessRequest().

Why are the async methods being called when I haven't done anything to call them?  I don't want asynchronous handling, and I certainly didn't do anything explicit to get it.  My controllers all derive from Controller, not AsyncController.

I don't have the source code with me right now, but I can add it later if needed.  I was hoping someone might know some of the reasons why BeginProcessRequest might be called when it's not wanted.

Comment: I tried an out-of-the box MVC 2 app with the System.Web.Mvc source and with zero changes BeginProcessRequest is always called and ProcessRequest is not.  Is the default handling in MVC 2 asynchronous?  I've been operating under the assumption that the default handling was synchronous, but it appears I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brad Wilson responded to my post on the Asp.net forums with the following answer http://forums.asp.net/t/1547898.aspx:

> Short answer: yes.
>
> With the addition of AsyncController,
> the MvcHandler class needs to be an
> IHttpAsyncHandler now, which means
> that as far as the ASP.NET core
> runtime is concerned, the entry points
> are now BeginProcessRequest and
> EndProcessRequest, not ProcessRequest.

It sounds like ProcessRequest is not even called anymore, but I could be mistaken.  I can say that I haven't seen it in my testing.